Using Ajax for Labels
I am working on a website page that displays and loads up the menu details once the user clicks on a label by using ajax but it seems that it is not working, I am new to ajax if anyone could review my code and tell me what I did wrong, I would much appreciate it.
This is the main file "View_catering.php"
    <?php 
     include 'header.html'; 
     include 'Database.php';
     include 'CateringManager.php';
   ?>

    <?php
     session_start(); // Start the session at the beginning of the script

     // Initialize the database connection
     $dbc = new Database();

     // Check if the database connection failed
     if (!$dbc) {
      die('Could not connect: '. mysqli_connect_error());
     }

     $caterings = new CateringManager($dbc);
     $menuService = $caterings->getAllServices();


   ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
      <style>
            <!--there is styling but removed it to make the coding short--> 
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
    <div class="Catering-Main">
    <h1>Catering Options</h1>
    <br>
    <div class="Breakfast">
        <div class="Breakfast-Container">
            <img src="images/Breakfast.jpg">
            <br><br>
            <!--once clicked on the label it should load up the menu details-->
            <label for="catering_breakfast" onclick="loadMenu('breakfast')">Breakfast</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="Lunch">
        <div class="Lunch-Container">
            <img src="images/Lunch.jpg">
            <br><br>
            <!--once clicked on the label it should load up the menu details-->
            <label for="catering_lunch" onclick="loadMenu('lunch')">Lunch</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="Cold-Beverages">
        <div class="ColdBev-Container">
            <img src="images/coldBeverages.jpg">
            <br><br>
            <!--once clicked on the label it should load up the menu details-->
            <label for="catering_coldBev" onclick="loadMenu('coldBev')">Cold Beverages</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="Hot-Beverages">
        <div class="HotBev-Container">
            <img src="images/hotBeverages.jpg">
            <br><br>
            <!--once clicked on the label it should load up the menu details-->
            <label for="catering_hotBev" onclick="loadMenu('hotBev')">Hot Beverages</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
<!-- JavaScript Section -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadMenu(service) {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("menuDetails").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };

            var url = "CateringMenuPage.php?service=" + encodeURIComponent(service);
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>

<!-- Placeholder for loaded menu details -->
<div id="menuDetails"></div>

</body><!-- comment -->
</html>

<?php include 'footer.html';?>


This is the file that is related to ajax and should display the menu details "CateringMenuPage.php"
 <?php
    include 'Database.php';

    // Get the service parameter from the GET request
    $service = $_GET['service'];

    // Initialize the database connection
    $dbc = new Database();

    // Check if the database connection failed
    if (!$dbc) {
        die('Could not connect: '. mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // Prepare the SQL query
    $query = "SELECT ServiceName, Description, Price FROM CateringService WHERE ServiceName=?";
    $stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $service);

    // Execute the query
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    // Fetch the result
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    // Output the result as HTML
    echo "<div>";
    echo "<h2>". htmlspecialchars($row['ServiceName']). "</h2>";
    echo "<p>Description: ". htmlspecialchars($row['Description']). "</p>";
    echo "<p>Price: $". htmlspecialchars($row['Price']). "</p>";
    echo "</div>";
   ?>


This is the sql CateringService table (-- Creating the Catering Service table
CREATE TABLE CateringService (
ServiceID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
ServiceName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PricePerUnit DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ServiceID)
);)
and tha table have four rows of data.
I double checked everything even using the link  for the label but it still not loading up the menu details.)

What debugging have you done? Start by using your browser's console and network tools to see what's happening

You need first to identify what kind of problem you're having: 1) is loadMenu() being executed? 2) is the AJAX call being fired? 3) is xmlhttp returning anything at all? Depending on that, you can start focusing your debugging either of your HTML/JS, on the AJAX connection, or on your PHP, respectively. That's when your browser's console is of special help, like @ADyson said. If you get more specific details, and need help on it, feel free to update your question so we can help you further.

Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, an HTML problem, or an SQL problem?
